# Suppose E ⊆ Z is nonempty and bounded above. Show that sup(E) ∈ E. In particular, sup(E) ∈ Z.

Tags: proof-verification

I think that since E is a subset of Z than all the element must be integer.then sup(E) must exist in E. I really do not know how to prove this. could someone help?

Comment: If $sup(E)$ is not an integer then $sup(E)-(sup(E)-[sup(E)])/2$ is still an upper bound and smaller than $sup(E)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that $\sup(E) = $ the maximal element of $E$. Another argument: the set $E$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and bounded above, hence $sup(E)\in E$.